# Add line items based on quantity

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add a line item based on the users input in a quantity text box.

So if the user types in a quantity of 2 the page will show:

text line for item 1

text line for item 2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#Quantity').change(function() {
  var textualValue = $(this).val();
  var numericValue = parseInt(textualValue);

  if (!isNaN(numericValue))
    modifyDOMWithNumber(numericValue);
})


function modifyDOMWithNumber(number) {
   var ul = $('ul#someListToAlter').empty();
   var item;

   for (var i=0; i<number; i++) {
      item = $("<li>");
      item.text("Text line for item "+i);
      ul.append(item);
   }
}

</script>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="none" id="Quantity" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow @roasted you do have magical power :)

Comment: That's nice.  Is there a question here, or are you just telling us this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking down the problem:

1. You need to parse the user input
2. and manipulate the DOM accordingly

First you need to do something like (you'd need to modify this to fit you case) :

```
$('#someTextInputWithThisID').change(function() {
  var textualValue = $(this).val();
  var numericValue = parseInt(textualValue);
  if (!isNaN(numericValue))
    modifyDOMWithNumber(numericValue);
})
```

Where, in `modifyDOMWithNumber` you'd have your code to reflect that input. Example:

```
function modifyDOMWithNumber(number) {
   var ul = $('ul#someListToAlter').empty();
   var item;
   for (var i=0; i<number; i++) {
      item = $("<li>");
      item.text("Text line for item "+(i+1));
      ul.append(item);
   }
}
```

Of course, all of this serves as an example to give you a general idea.